# How to run 2 queries at a time as single query

Tags: mysql

Hi I have database like

```
   name    to   Maths Science
    stud1 stud2   30    50
  **stud1 stud1   40    60**
    stud2 stud2   20    90
  **stud3 stud1   60    80**
```

And When I query my database  as stud1 I need to get the output as
that I need to get the values for stud1 for himself he rated and avg  of all values belongs to him has ** in the above

```
 AVg(Maths) Maths
    50           40
```

can any one suggest me how to do this query.

Comment: So the 40 value you are looking for is that of `name='stud1', to='stud1'`, wherein both of those columns are `stud1`?

Comment: Yes I want output as shown In the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT AVG(maths) from tbl),MATHS from tbl
```

Comment: That's going to average _all_ rows for _all students_

Answer (score 0):

The Avg() function is a group operation, where as the select is a row operation. You should not try to combine them together in a single query since it contains redundant info. However, if you want to go ahead you do this:

```
select to, name, maths, science, (select avg(maths) from table), 
(select avg(science) from table) from table where to ="stud1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure why answers are tending to ignore what is averaged:

```
SELECT
  AVG(Maths) AS AvgMaths,
  MAX(IF(name=to), Maths, NULL)) AS Maths
FROM some_table WHERE to = 'stud1'
```

Note: I would have thought the average is: 43.  (3 rows have 'stud1' in them, not 2)

Comment: I could not understand your question.

Comment: @user2787300 It wasn't really a question.  Basically why wasn't the first row in your table included in the average (name is 'stud1')

Comment: It was just a model for my database. And I am a beginner so I asked this question.